# How to get smooth scrolling functionality on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just as the title states. Initially I tried to use polyfill smoothscroll by just adding this to the bottom of my body tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4/dist/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>
```

But this didn't seem to really do anything. I'm clearly missing something here. Do I need to add something for the smoothscroll functionality to work? Are there any other vanilla js solutions to have smoothscroll work on Safari?

Comment: Seems like there'd be a reason why their example page works on safari but not on your page. Any chance you could post a link to get a look-see?

Comment: @Kinglish found an alternative below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Zenscroll, It is a JavaScript library that enables animated vertical scrolling to an element or position within your document or within a scrollable element

It works on

- Android Browser 2.2+
- Chrome for Android Chrome 14+ (probably earlier too)
- Edge
- Firefox 9+
- Internet Explorer 9+
- iOS Safari 4+
- Opera 10.6+
- etc..

https://zengabor.github.io/zenscroll/

Comment: Zenscroll works perfectly! I did deviate from the instructions and use the following code at the bottom of my <body> tag rather than downloading the .js file directly: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/zenscroll@4.0.2/zenscroll-min.js"></script>`